# Android Button text positioning

Tags: android, button, uitextposition

How can I make the text appear NEXT to a button, instead of being ON the button?

Here is a screenshot of what i need:

[image]

You can see the text on the first button. It is written ON the button, and I couldn't move it from it (aside from changing the gravity, but it's not really what I am after).
Next to a second button, I put a label, as a guideline of something I would like to achieve.

Is there a way of doing this in Android?
it is pretty straightforward in ObjectiveC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a TextView instead of a button.
TextViews are clickable, the very same way as buttons are.

And the listeners are assigned in the same way as you would do with buttons.
So, very small changes in code are needed (renaming your controls prefixes and changing type from Button to TextView, which is really a trivial task).

You can add a drawable to it, by specifying the attribute `android:dawableLeft="@drawable/my_icon"`, for a left side graphics

You can use drawableLeft and/or drawableRigth and/or drawableTop and/or drawableBottom.
You can specify drawablePadding, to add some space between the graphics and the text

This is a best practice, in keeping your design hyerarchy as flatten as possible.

Note that you are not limited to images... you can use xml drawables too!

Comment: I use it every time I can - it's a life saver! Note that you are not limited to images... you can use xml drawables too!

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your second `Button` and `TextView` in a horizontal `LinearLayout`. This will cause the text to be to the right of the button.

Comment: This will add another level in the hyerarchy, while better design guidelines say to flatten your designs as more as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try Relative Layout. There is one attribute align_leftof

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` to wrap the two elements and easily use `layout_rightOf` to position the `TextView` next to the `Button`, hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Button2"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btn2"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

It's not perfect example but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is Very Simple. Just Use     `android:drawableLeft`.   In Your Button,  drawable image as follows :

```
       <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="button"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>
```